# Husky simulator for ROS-Lunar?

Tags: gazebo, simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 17.04.

I have ROS-Lunar and I wish to use Husky simulation in my Gazebo.

I tried installing it with
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-husky-simulator

but it says "Unable to locate package"

"ros-lunar-husky-simulator" doesnt work either.

Isnt Husky supported by Lunar? Do I need to use ROS-Indigo to get this to work? What to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269575/husky-simulator-for-ros-lunar?/) by [MukulKhanna](https://answers.ros.org/users/31696/mukulkhanna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2017-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Husky is currently only supported on Indigo. Kinetic is planned whereas, lunar is not but should work if installed from source.  I believe that the husky repo has a kinetic-devel branch that should work if installed from source.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2017-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MukulKhanna](https://answers.ros.org/users/31696/mukulkhanna/) on 2017-08-26**:
Can you please guide me as to how I can get the Husky simulator or any other simulator for that matter, in my Gazebo that came with ROS-Lunar.

You have mentioned something about installing from source,
how does that work and can it get me to using Husky with the ros lunar specs?